# kapt2 and butterknife produce lint error: Expected resource of type id

Tags: android, kotlin, lint, butterknife, kapt2

When updating to kotlin 1.0.4 and kapt2 I am getting the following lint-errors:

```
../generated/source/kapt2/withMapsWithAnalyticsForPlayRelease/org/ligi/passandroid/ui/pass_view_holder/EditViewHolder_ViewBinding.java:20: Expected resource of type id
  17     super(target, source);
  18 
  19     View view;
  20     view = Utils.findRequiredView(source, 2131624091, "method 'onNavigateClick'");
  21     view2131624091 = view;
  22     view.setOnClickListener(new DebouncingOnClickListener() {
../generated/source/kapt2/withMapsWithAnalyticsForPlayRelease/org/ligi/passandroid/ui/pass_view_holder/EditViewHolder_ViewBinding.java:28: Expected resource of type id
  25         target.onNavigateClick();
  26       }
  27     });
  28     view = Utils.findRequiredView(source, 2131624092, "method 'onCalendarClick'");
  29     view2131624092 = view;
  30     view.setOnClickListener(new DebouncingOnClickListener() {
```

Is there a way to switch off this check for these files? I do not want to disable this check globally

Comment: You might want to explore the Kotlin discussion forums for the EAP, or the Kotlin Slack channel #eap for issues of experimental features, which I think includes KAPT2.

Comment: There's a `butterknife` for `kotlin` called `kotterknife` - check if changing this library would help.